# Retrieving the 25 most recently added entries from all tables in a MySQL database

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a MySQL database (named "sitefeather") which will eventually have several tables with identical structures.  The structure is this:

```
id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, site VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, action1 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, action2 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, createddatetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE (site)
```

I would like to print a list of the 25 most recently added entries (called "site" in each table) across all tables.  How can I do this with PHP?

Thanks in advance,

John

EDIT:  How would I do this for a number of tables that will be variable?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to do something along the lines of:

```
(
    select 't' as table_name, id, createdatetime 
    from t 
    order by createdatetime desc 
    limit 25
)
union
(
    select 'u' as table_name, id, createdatetime 
    from u 
    order by createdatetime desc 
    limit 25
)
union
(
    select 'v' as table_name, id, createdatetime 
    from v 
    order by createdatetime desc 
    limit 25
)
order by createdatetime desc
limit 25
```

This should guarantee you the benefit of any index you have on the `createdatetime` field of the various tables, and will allow you to determine from which table each of the 25 resulting ids were selected.

Comment: Upvoted this one instead of gahooa's as it's a little more optimised (limit 25 per table)

Comment: How would I do this for a variable number of tables?

Comment: You add more queries to the union; copy and paste the block `union ( ... )` and change the table name and the string-literal of the table name.

Comment: That doesn't work for a variable number of tables... the number should be generally increasing.  I can't change the code each time a table is added to the database.

Comment: You can't write one query to select the names of the tables _and_ query from those tables; that would involve a translation from string literals to identifiers, which MySQL does not allow.  The closest you can get to what you want would be to query `information_schema.tables` for the tables you want to use, then build your query dynamically using that list of tables.

Answer (score 2):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
(SELECT id FROM table1)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM table2)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM table3)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM tableN)
  ORDER BY createdatetime DESC 
  LIMIT 25
```

You will *really* want to look into indexes for optimizations here...

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing this, or querying all tables at once for other reason, very often, you might want to [set up a MERGE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html) that allows easier access to the combined data.

```
CREATE TABLE merged_table (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    site VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    action1 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL,
    action2 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL,
    createddatetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE (site)) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(table1,table2,table3,tableN) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

However, this method is only efficient if you're going to be querying the same tables every time.